# Where is Ruby documentation for Mime::HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say we have the following auto-generated code in a controller:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @person.update(person_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @person }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And lets say that I'm curious enough to want to know what object `format`
returns in order to know what object is `json` or `html` invoked on. Where is the documentation to answer those simple questions?

I tried `ri format`, and got this (among others):

```
Returns the MIME type for the format used in the request.

GET /posts/5.xml   | request.format => Mime::XML
GET /posts/5.xhtml | request.format => Mime::HTML
GET /posts/5       | request.format => Mime::HTML or MIME::JS, or request.accepts.first
```

If I do `ri Mime::HTML`, I get this:

```
Nothing known about Mime::HTML
```

But there is documentation for `Mime::Type` (which I think is what `format` above returns), and it states that this class has an instance method, `method_missing`, which I suppose is what invoked when we do `format.html` or `format.json`. What I want to know is: If I'm right about the `method_missing` fallback trick, then why there is no documentation for `Mime::HTML.method_missing` for example? And why there is no documentation for `Mime::HTML` or `Mime::XML` at the first place? In other words, what is the relation between `Mime::HTML` or `Mime::XML`, and `Mime:Type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_types.rb

And this:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb#L162-L174

To answer your question: `Mime::HTML` and `Mime::XML` are dynamically-generated constants, using `Mime::Type.register`.